# How to use firebase with Godot?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, godot

Is there anyone using firebase with godot. I couldn't find any proper documentation for it.

I tried this repo, didn't say anything related to google anaytics.

can anyone help ?

I'm using godot 4.2, building game for mobile platform

https://github.com/GodotNuts/GodotFirebase

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems the linked repository is not up to date. And no, There is no documentation. It is simply consuming the Firebase web API (which you can in Firebase documentation) with Godot HTTP requests (which you can find in Godot documentation). I don't know about Google Analytics.

Comment: There seems to be good documentation here https://github.com/GodotNuts/GodotFirebase/wiki